# Derivation of Feynman rules in many-body theory

Tags: feynman-diagrams, perturbation-theory, greens-functions, many-body

In textbooks on many-body quantum physics (e.g. Fetter and Walecka), Feynman diagrams are typically introduced after formulating the Dyson perturbative expansion of the Green's function using Wicks theorem. Then the Feynman diagrams follow as a way to conveniently represent the resulting integral equations.

In most literature however, I have noticed that the language is somewhat different. Typically, after introducing the Hamiltonian a certain quantity of interest will be introduced, typically the single-particle Green's function of self-energy. Then there is often a sentence like:

*To evaluate this quantity of interest we sum the set of Feynman diagrams shown in Fig. X*

Then Fig. X will contain the perturbative series already written in terms of Feynman diagrams. It seems that the step where this series is formulated, as I find in the textbooks, is typically skipped. I can think of two possible reasons for this:

1. The actual formulation of the Feynman rules from Dyson's equation and Wicks theorem is seen as trivial, and hence not repeated in typical papers. Even if the system is not a standard system treated in other literature.
2. There is actually a faster or more intuitive way to write down the relevant Feynman diagrams from the Hamiltonian, without having to resort to the perturbative expansion explicitly. If this is the case then I would love to see a textbook where such a procedure is explained. Currently whenever I want to understand a paper I go through the whole perturbative expansion for the respective Hamiltonian, which is a very tedious and time consuming process.

I would be very appreciative if someone more familiar with this field could tell me which of these is true. Thanks!

Comment: It is very much 2, to the point that *every* textbook on Feynman diagrams should be explaining this. It is really the entire point of Feynman diagrams

Answer (score 2):

Usually the texts like Fetter&Walecka or AGD explain how the Feynmann diagrams arise from the Dyson expansion, explain the cancellation of disconnected diagrams, etc., and derive the *Feynmann rules*, which allow writing diagrams for higher orders directly without bothering to write the full Feynmann-Dyson expansion. Thus, in the following discussions the Feynmann-Dyson expansion is not needed anymore.
It might be that Fetter&Walecka, being somewhat more pedagogical (i.e. easy on math), does not go in the details of diagrams counting... I do recall them however performing infinite summations of bubbles and ladder diagrams, where they clearly do not spell all the diagrams beyond the 3-rd or 4-th order.

In my memory the books deriving diagrammatic expansion from path integrals, e.g., Negele&Orland, follow the same logic. This is likely also true for basic QFT books, like Peskin or Mandl&Shaw.